# Characterization of upper-semicontinuous mapping

Tags: general-topology

Iam looking for a proof of the following assertion:

> Let $X$ be a real reflexive Banach space, let $T\colon X\rightrightarrows X'$ a point-to-set mapping such that for every $x\in X$ the set $T(x)$ is weak closed. Then $T$ is upper-semicontinuous, if the set $\{x\in X\mid T(x) \cap A \}$ is weak closed for every weak closed set $A\subset X$.

Comment: For me the latter is the definition of upper semicontinouous maps. What is yours?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Thank you. I added my question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Iam using the following definition: $T\colon X \rightrightarrows X'$ is called upper-semicontinuous in $x\in \mathcal D(T)$ iff for every neighborhood $V$ of $T(x)$ there existis a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ with $T(U)\subset V$.

Comment: I thought as much (I googled, and remembered an old definition from the Vietoris topology). See my answer. I assumed the domain is all of $X$, but that's irrelevant I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is upper-semicontinuous, let $A$ be a weak closed subset of $X$.

Define $F = \{x \in X: T(x) \cap A  \neq \emptyset \}$. Now suppose that $p \notin F$, so that $T(p) \subseteq (X' \setminus A)$. By the definition of upper-semicontinuity I found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-121-02/S0002-9939-1994-1215199-4/S0002-9939-1994-1215199-4.pdf), there exists a neighbourhood $U_p$ of $p$ such that for all $x \in U_p$, $T(x) \subseteq (X' \setminus A)$, which says that $U_p \cap F = \emptyset$. So every point outside $F$ has a neighbourhood that misses $F$, so $F$ is closed.

On the other hand, suppose that the condition holds, and let $O$ be open and $p \in X$ be such that $T(p) \subseteq O$. Then $X \setminus O$ is closed, so by assumption $F = \{x \in X: T(x) \cap (X \setminus O) \neq \emptyset \}$ is closed. As $p \notin F$ by definition there is a neighbourhood $U_p$ of such for all $x \in U_p$ we have $U_p \cap F = \emptyset$, which means that for all such $x$ we have $T(x) \cap (X' \setminus O) = \emptyset$ or $T(x) \subseteq O$, as required. so $T$ is upper-semicontinuous.

I don't use the assumption on the $T(x)$ images directly, but this is often because in this context these sets are always closed, I presume. Also this works in any set of topological spaces and multivalued maps between them. The notions are quite general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my really late replay. I am a bit confused because I assumed $\subset X$ and you write $X'\setminus A$. Maybe you can help me again